# Remote port access

Tags: ssh, port, redhat, remote-access

I was working on the intranet at work on a virtual machine set up for my project and at some point I have to access it by putting localhost:port number and it works.

Right now I'm home working on it and I can download/upload, use SSH, etc. But I cannot access the same port by putting URL:port number while everything else works.

I'm new to all this so please excuse my ignorance on what could be a very basic subject.<

P.S. the system administrator supposedly gave me full and complete access to the machine, including giving me full firewall permissions. I also have root access via SSH if needed.

THANK YOU!

Comment: What sort of access? Accessing a web server on the vm? Accessing a remote desktop / via vnc?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
ssh -L port:localhost:port remotehost
```

and then accessing localhost:port as if you were at work.

(n.b. you don't need root access.)

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't noticed you answered. The problem was solved otherwise though, the port was closed at my work's firewall. It is now open and everything works fine, no need to route.